# Solve Differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y' = \frac{2y^{2}-xy}{x^2-xy+y^2} $$
so i have done it by making a substitution  $ u=y/x $
$$ u+u'x = \frac{2u^2-u}{1-u+u^{2}} $$
$$ \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{1-u+u^{2}}{3u^{2}-2u-u^{3}}du $$
and when i want to integrate it i need to find integral of a right side which is kinda tought so present it as
 $$ \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{1}{u-1}du-\frac{1}{2u}du-\frac{3}{2(u-2)}du $$
and after that i have no problem but this substitution took me a while, so maybe is there any option to do this example a bit faster?

Comment: Seems perfect to me!

Comment: Since the equation is homogeneous , your substitution seems fine.

Comment: I think this is the fastest way to do it if you exclude Wolfram alpha :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y'=\dfrac{2(\frac{y}{x}-\frac12)}{(\frac{y}{x}-\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$
$$\int y'=\int\dfrac{\left((\frac{y}{x}-\frac12)^2+\frac34\right)'}{(\frac{y}{x}-\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$
$$y=\ln\left((\frac{y}{x}-\frac12)^2+\frac34\right)+C$$

Comment: Nice observation skills!